# jQuery Datatable not working in symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, datatable

I have done all required steps but I don't know why my datatable is not showed. I have included `jquery.dataTables.css` and `jquery.dataTables.js`.

```
**view.html.twig**

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/style.css') }}" >
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/bootstrap.css') }}" >
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/bootstrap-grid.css') }}" >
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/bootstrap-theme.css') }}" >
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}" >
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css') }}" >
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/demo.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>STUDENT INFORMATION FORM</h1>
    <table class="container" id="table_view" border="1"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>USER NAME</th>
                <th>FIRST NAME</th>
                <th>LAST NAME</th>
                <th>EMAIL ID</th>
                <th>PASSWORD</th>
                <th>EDIT</th>
                <th>DELETE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for key in view %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{  key.UserName }}</td>
                <td>{{  key.FirstName }}</td>
                <td>{{  key.LastName }}</td>
                <td>{{  key.EmailId }}</td>
                <td>{{  key.Password }}</td>
                <td><span class="link"><a href="/my_project/web/app_dev.php/edit/{{ key.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Edit</a><span></td>
                <td><span class="link"><a href="/my_project/web/app_dev.php/delete/{{ key.id }}" class="deleteUser btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</a><span></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#table_view').DataTable();
          });
    </script>


{% endblock %}



        **demo.js**
```

This is my `demo.js` file i am using Ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create").click(function(){
    alert('You Can See Student Information Form');

        //var formURL = "{{ path('form') }}";
        //var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: formURL,
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("#form_person_edit").serialize(),
            success: function(res){
            $(".ajax_response").html();

            if(res.status == 'success'){
            window.location.href = viewURL;
            }
            }   
    });
    });
    });
```

I don't know where I did a mistake.

Comment: it's hard to help without you giving us the javascript error message that you are getting. Inspect you webpage with your browser , go to console tab and post what error you are getting here. from first sight you should change the order of your js files call. jquery should be the very first , demo.js should be the very last

Answer (score 0):

By default block javascripts gets rendered at the end of the html. So in your case you are calling $('#table_view').DataTable(); too early.
Move:

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#table_view').DataTable();
          });
    </script>
```

at the end of block javascripts. And in your base.html.twig make sure block javascripts is defined after block body.

Comment: I solved, i removed my {% extends 'base.html.twig' %} form the view.html.twig then my datatable is working.

Comment: But in my console having error so how can i remove it " Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6 "

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script> must be your first line in javascripts block.

Comment: Bootstrap has a dependency on Jquery. So you must load Jquery before Bootstrap. Always pay attention to the order of your assets, both javascript and css files.

Comment: Thankyou very much.